# Converting ISO 8601 Date in format "YYYY-MM-DDT12:00:00.000Z" to "DD.MM.YYYY" using jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a Backbone application and from REST API data, I'm getting the date which Mongo generated in ISO format **YYYY-MM-DDT12:00:00.000Z**. To display in human readable in front-end view (jqgrid colmodel) table grid view, I need to show users a simple format **DD.MM.YYYY**. The condition is, I need to convert the date by converting only the view of the backend date to this new format.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you just want to re-arrange the year, month and day part of the string you are getting – then why don’t you just do so? Can be solved with simple string manipulation, since all offsets and lengths are fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ISO 8601 time date into plain English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498619/convert-iso-8601-time-date-into-plain-english)

Comment: The date is coming from the backend, I'm just displaying as it is using the API sequential order in a table format. The application does CRUD for some inputted data. I tried to convert it in render() function but it didnt helped that. I'm trying to find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow made it work by writing my own library. This is just the instance of code you need to include for changing or converting the date coming from the server side JSON schema.

Code:

```
cacheElements: function() {
  this.$datePickers = this.$el.find('.datepicker');
  this.$datePickerStart = this.$datePickers.filter('.start');
  this.$datePickerEnd = this.$datePickers.filter('.end');
  this.$loader = this.$el.find('.timeframe-loader');
},

render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));

  this.cacheElements();

  this.$datePickers.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });

  this.delegateEvents();

  return this;
},

_onError: function(model, error) {
  this._hideLoader();
  var $where;
  if (error.where == 'startDate') {
    $where = this.$datePickerStart.closest('div');
  } else if (error.where == 'endDate') {
    $where = this.$datePickerEnd.closest('div');
  }
  new Tooltip.View({
    srcElement: $where,
    content: error.message,
    position: 'bottom'
  });
},

_onClickSendData: function() {
  var start = this.$datePickerStart.val();
  var end = this.$datePickerEnd.val();

  var startDate = humanDateStringToJSDateString(start);
  var endDate = humanDateStringToJSDateString(end);

  // If didn't actually change, do nothing:
  var modelStartDate = this.model.get('startDate');
  var modelEndDate = this.model.get('endDate');
  if (this._compareYYYMMDD(new Date(startDate), modelStartDate) !== 0 || this._compareYYYMMDD(new Date(endDate), modelEndDate) !== 0) {
    this._showLoader();

    this.model.set({
      startDate: new Date(startDate),
      endDate: new Date(endDate)
    });
  }
},

_compareYYYMMDD: function(date1, date2) {
  var num1 = dateToString(date1).replace('-','');
  var num2 = dateToString(date2).replace('-','');
  return date1 - date2;
},

_showLoader: function() {
  this.$loader.show();
},

_hideLoader: function() {
  this.$loader.hide();
},

setEndDate: function() {
  this.$datePickerStart.val(dateToDottedString(addDays(new Date(), - App.state.get('timeframe'))));
  this.$datePickerEnd.val(dateToDottedString(new Date()));
}
```

});

Let me know if you have difficulty in understanding the logic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moments.js](http://momentjs.com) to parse the string and output it in a human readable format.

Comment: I do not think it makes sense using a JS-library if you want to convert only one date.

Comment: Its not just one date. Its a jqgrid colmodel table coming from the MongoDB server. I need to parse same functionality for every date. Although, moments.js would be last option to try, but I'm sure there is something easier and quicker way to do that! Still thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this:

```
var convertDate = function(date){
    var date = date.match(/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/);
    if(date == null){
        return false;   
    }else{
        var dateObj = {
            dateFormat1 : date[3] + '.' + date[2] + '.' + date[1],
            dateFormat2 : date[1] + '-' + date[2] + '-' + date[3],
            dateFormat3 : date[2] + '/' + date[3] + '/' + date[1],
            time : date[4] + ':' + date[5] + ':' + date[6],
        };
        return dateObj;
    }
};

var obj = console.log(convertDate('2013-04-09T12:00:00.000Z').dateFormat2);
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'm trying to parse it now with server data.

Comment: Your approach is smart. I'm trying to use your functionality in flexigrid.js main file, so that in future it convert to every format in such date.

Answer (score -2):

I doubt jQuery has any date parsing/formatting functionality.

You need to parse it and covert to the desired format yourself.

Comment: Folks, minuses look very surprising here :). Please share the reason for that :)

Comment: While this "answer" is technically correct, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Juhana, thanks for explanation :). I thought the answer was within the scope of the question. To be able to help more, the question should be clarified :).