# how do i change the mongodb date format

Tags: javascript, mongodb-query

I want to write a query to retrieve the date in mongodb.

```
{
  "created_at": "2018-05-29T14:04:54.000Z",
  "origin": "mongo",
  "id": "111111111",
  "data": {
  "_id": "11111111111",
  "id": 111111111111,
  "dcre": "2018-05-29T14:04:54.324Z",
}
```

I want to have `dcre": "2018-05-29"` or `dcre": "2018/05/29"` instead of `dcre": "2018-05-29T14:04:54.324Z"`

I try

```
async find(date) {
  const res = await this.db.collection('table').find({
    dcre:date
  }).limit(500).toArray();
  return res;
}
```

but it does not work

Comment: You want to convert the iso 8601 date to plain English? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498619/convert-iso-8601-time-date-into-plain-english

Comment: Theoretically JavaScript shouldn't care (too much) how you store the date in the database and just be able to call "something" passing a date. You don't want to update your JavaScript code if you change DB or the format you store the date in. That "something"/middle-tier? should be responsible for taking the JavaScript date and make sense of it before passing on the query to the database. - I said "too much" as it is in general a good idea to pass dates from the front-end to the back-end in reverse (`'2018-05-31'`) as some serilizers get their knickers in a twist with day and month positions.

Comment: During the recovery I would like to have only  "2018-05-29" and not "2018-05-29T14:04:54.324Z"